# Continuity equation with measures / Vizualise the divergence of a measure?

Tags: measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, intuition

I kind of understand the meaning of the continuity equation when $\rho_t(x)$ is a density $$\partial_t\rho+div_x(\rho_t v)=0$$ Which means that the time variation of the density in a point is the divergence of the momentum. However, when $\rho(t)$ is a general probability measure I am a bit confused. To understand this a bit better I consider as an example $\rho(t)=\delta_{z(t)}$. Then the weak formulation is $$\int_0^T\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\left[\partial_t\phi(t,x)+\langle v_t(x),\nabla_x\phi(x,t)\rangle d\delta_{z(t)}(x)dt\right]=0$$ and thus $$\int_0^T\left[\partial_t\phi(t,z(t))+\langle v_t(z(t)),\nabla_x\phi(z(t),t)\rangle dt\right]=0.$$ But can I still simplify this more?

**edit**

I think also my problem comes from the fact that I cannot really visualize intuitively what it means to be the derivative/divergence of a measure in the distributional sense. I understand the reasoning behind it with the integration by part and so on but I always prefer when there is some kind of visualization.

**edit**

Is $$\partial_t\rho_t+div_x(\rho_t v_t)=0$$ actually equivalent to $$\partial_t (f_{n}\star\rho_t)+div_x(f_n\star(\rho_t v_t))=0$$ for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$ where $f_n$ are the standard mollifiers?

Comment: What test functions $\phi$ are you using in your weak formulation?  (It looks like the initial condition is missing.)

Comment: I am using smooth compactly supported test functions. I guess the initial condition in the example with the diract would be $\rho(0)=\delta_{z(0)}$

Comment: If you think about the case when $\rho$ is a smooth function/density, you may notice that there should be $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} \rho(T,x) \phi(T,x) \, dx$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} \rho(0,x) \phi(0,x) \, dx$ terms in your weak formulation.  Hence my question.  (Often times weak formulations are given with test functions vanishing on $\mathbb{R}^{d} \times \{T\}$ or $\mathbb{R}^{d} \times \{0\}$.)

Comment: @PeterMorfe I think we may assume the test functions are in the set you suggest